# How to use if condition on enumerable inside where clause

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say i have a query, where i have to select specific products.

I have a class called recipe which has ienumerable about ingridients used.

At first i would like to take all the receipes which are not deleted, which is fairly easy:

```
var recipes = context.Recipes.Where(a=> !a.Deleted);
```

Now i would like to go through enumerable to select the ones that contain water for example. Which would be something like so

```
recipes = recipes.Where(a => a.Ingridients.Where(b => b.Name == "Water"));
```

But here lies the problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Any` instead of `Where` in the sub-query:

```
recipes = recipes.Where(a => a.Ingredients.Any(b => b.Name == "Water"));
```

It will return all recipes which contain `Water` as one of the ingredients.

Comment: That is clever. I swear I tried something like that out. Thank you again!
I will accept yours in 10 minutes, because then i can.